# Error when using Collections.sort()

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, comparable

I'm wondering why i'm getting an error after trying to sort the List.
The error happens when i try to sort the list containing "Student" objects.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class mainProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> classStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();

    //Add 4 students to List
        classStudents.add(new Student("Charles", 22));
        classStudents.add(new Student("Chris", 25));
        classStudents.add(new Student("Robert", 23));
        classStudents.add(new Student("Adam", 21));

    //sort and print
        Collections.sort(classStudents);    //Why does this not work?
        System.out.println("classStudent(Sorted) ---> "
        + Arrays.toString(classStudents.toArray()));
    }
}
```

---

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student>{
    // fields
    private String name;
    private int age;

    //Constructor
    public Student(String name, int age){ 
        name = name;
        age = age;
        }
    //Override compare
    public int CompareTo(Student otherStudent){
        if(this.age == otherStudent.age){
            return 0;
        } else if(this.age < otherStudent.temp){
            return -1;
        } else{
            return 1;
        }
    }

    //Override toString
    public String toString(){
        return this.name + " " + this.age;
    }
}
```

---

```
interface Comparable<Student>{
    int CompareTo(Student otherStudent); 
    String toString();
}
```

The Error is:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Student>). The inferred type Student is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

I do not understand what the error means and how to fix it. Your input will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may not be so obvious based on error message, but if you take a look at [documentation of `Collection.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) you fill find that this method (like rest of standard API methods) expects list of instances implementing *already defined in API interface* which in this case is [`java.lang.Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

So don't try to create your own `Comparable` interface. Remember that if some method expects some type, this type must be already defined somewhere (otherwise class with such method wouldn't compile because method can't use some unknown/undefined type).

Also comparing method defined in `java.util.Comparable` is `compareTo` not `CompareTo` (Java is case sensitive so these methods are not treated as equal).

---

Other problems are

- `Student` doesn't have `temp` field so

  ```
  } else if (this.age < otherStudent.temp) {
  ```

  should probably be

  ```
  } else if (this.age < otherStudent.age) {
  ```

  or even better, instead of this `age` comparing conditions `if(..<..){-1} else if(..==..){0} else {1}` simply use

  ```
  return Integer.compare(age, otherStudent.age);
  ```
- in constructor you need `this.name` to determine which `name` you are refering to. `this.name` means field of this instance, `name` is reference to variable passed to constructor. So you need

  ```
  public Student(String name, int age) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Java defines its own Comparable interface. delete yours and import theres, the collections method uses the java one.

Answer (score 2):

Made small changes, have a look:

**MainProgram.java**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainProgram {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("HI !!!");
            List<Student> classStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();

        //Add 4 students to List
            classStudents.add(new Student("Charles", 22));
            classStudents.add(new Student("Chris", 25));
            classStudents.add(new Student("Robert", 23));
            classStudents.add(new Student("Adam", 21));

        //sort and print
            Collections.sort(classStudents);    //Why does this not work?
            System.out.println("classStudent(Sorted) ---> "
            + Arrays.toString(classStudents.toArray()));
        }
    }
```

**Student.java**

```
class Student implements java.lang.Comparable<Student>{
    // fields
    private String name;
    private int age;

    //Constructor
    public Student(String name, int age){ 
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        }

    //Override compare
    public int compareTo(Student otherStudent){
        if(this.age == otherStudent.age){
            return 0;
        } else if(this.age < otherStudent.age){
            return -1;
        } else{
            return 1;
        }
    }

    //Override toString
    public String toString(){
        return this.name + " " + this.age;
    }
}
```

**Output :** classStudent(Sorted) ---> [Adam 21, Charles 22, Robert 23, Chris 25]

Answer (score 0):

Your `Student` class needs to implement the `java.lang.Comparable` interface if you are going to sort on it. Otherwise, how could the method possibly know on what criteria to sort?

This should be helpful: [Why should a Java class implement comparable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718383/java-class-implements-comparable)

Answer (score 0):

First, there's a typo where you override the Comparable interface method, "compareTo()" --- it should be a lower-case "c", not upper-case.

Second, I don't know what you're trying to do with the last bit that starts, "interface Comparable". Drop that part --- you don't need it.

The Comparable interface is part of the API.

Cheers.