# how to sort Java combobox when filled with Vector?

Tags: java, sorting, vector, combobox

context :

i'm working on an applet witch manage fidelity cards. past version of the app had been done by an other developper. there is no documentation. i have to improve it.

problem :

to reach a customer, the app have some combobox. those combobox are filled by vertors

i try to sort item in the combobox but fail each times

i've read things about Collections.sort(x); where x could be a List or a Vector

but wherever i put the instruction for sorting elements, eclipse mark sort with this error :

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Vector<NomClient>). The inferred type NomClient is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

here is the code of the combobox :

```
    private JComboBox<Object> getComboBox() {
    if (this.comboBox == null) {
        this.comboBox = new JComboBox<Object>();
        this.comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {

                try {
                    SelectionNumeroCarteFidelite2.this.name = SelectionNumeroCarteFidelite2.this.comboBox
                            .getSelectedItem().toString();
                    SelectionNumeroCarteFidelite2.this.mod2 = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Object>(
                            Select.listePrenomclientfidelite(SelectionNumeroCarteFidelite2.this.name));
                    SelectionNumeroCarteFidelite2.this.comboBox_1
                            .setModel(SelectionNumeroCarteFidelite2.this.mod2);
                    SelectionNumeroCarteFidelite2.this.lblTaperOuSlectionner
                            .setVisible(false);
                } catch (final Exception e1) {


                    final String message = "Choix Impossible - Merci de vérifier votre sélection";
                    System.out.print("Nom " + message);
                    final AlerteSelection fenetre = new AlerteSelection(
                            SelectionNumeroCarteFidelite2.this.interfaceactuelle,
                            message);
                    fenetre.setVisible(true);
                    SelectionNumeroCarteFidelite2.this.interfaceactuelle
                            .setEnabled(false);
                    SelectionNumeroCarteFidelite2.this.lblValider
                            .setVisible(false);
                    SelectionNumeroCarteFidelite2.this.lblTaperOuSlectionner
                            .setVisible(true);
                }

            }
        });
        this.comboBox.setEnabled(false);
        this.comboBox.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        this.comboBox.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        this.comboBox.setEditable(true);
        this.comboBox.setBorder(null);
        this.comboBox.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.comboBox.setBounds(528, 426, 278, 22);

        this.mod = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Object>(
                Select.listenomclientfidelite());
        this.comboBox.setModel(this.mod);
        AutoCompletion.enable(this.comboBox);

    }
    return this.comboBox;
}
```

here is the code of the Select.listenomclientfidelite()

```
public static Object[] listenomclientfidelite() {
    final Vector<NomClient> requete = new Vector<NomClient>();
    try {
        c = Connexion.getCon();
        final String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT NOMCLIENT FROM CARTE_DE_FIDELITE INNER JOIN CLIENT ON CLIENT.IDCLIENT=CARTE_DE_FIDELITE.IDCLIENT";
        preStm = c.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = preStm.executeQuery();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.print("erreur" + e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        requete.add(null);
        NomClient liste;
        while (rs.next()) {
            liste = new NomClient();
            liste.setNom(rs.getString(1));
            requete.add(liste);
            System.out.println("listenomclientfidelite, liste is : "+liste);
        }
        rs.close();
        preStm.close();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.print("errorlistenom" + e.getMessage());
    }

    return requete.toArray(new Object[0]);
```

After beeing advised by Hovercraft Full Of Eels to modify my class NomClient, i understood that my NomCli class was the problen and not the use of vector, so here is a new step but no solution yet , so here is my Modified NomClient Class :

```
public class NomClient implements Comparable<NomClient> {

String nom;

public String getNom() {
    return this.nom;
}

public void setNom(final String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.nom;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(NomClient other) {
    System.out.println("nom : "+this.nom);
    System.out.println("nom to string : "+this.nom.toString());
    System.out.println(other.nom);
    System.out.println("compare to : "+other.nom.toString());       
    int last = this.nom.toString().compareTo(other.nom.toString());
    return last == 0 ? this.nom.compareTo(other.nom) : last;
}
```

}

i also have added Collection sort just before the return statement in sselect.listenomclientfidelite(),

like this  :

```
        Collections.sort(requete);

            return requete.toArray(new Object[0]);
```

Now i have to deal with a java.lang.NullPointerException. "other" is null

Does any one have a clue to properly sort my combobox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank to [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels) his solution was the good one.

i realised the first item of my vector was null it's why the comparable methode failed. so i worked around to handle this case, and here are the final implementation :

for NomClient.java :

```
public class NomClient implements Comparable<NomClient> {

String nom;

public String getNom() {
    return this.nom;
}

public void setNom(final String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.nom;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(NomClient other) {
    // compareTo should return < 0 if this is supposed to be
    // less than other, > 0 if this is supposed to be greater than
    // other and 0 if they are supposed to be equal
    int last = 10;
    if (other != null){
        last = -10;
        if (this.nom != null){
            last = this.nom.compareTo(other.nom);
            }
    }
    return last;
```

for Select.listenomclientfidelite()

```
public static Object[] listenomclientfidelite() {
    final Vector<NomClient> requete = new Vector<NomClient>();
    try {
        c = Connexion.getCon();
        final String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT NOMCLIENT FROM CARTE_DE_FIDELITE INNER JOIN CLIENT ON CLIENT.IDCLIENT=CARTE_DE_FIDELITE.IDCLIENT";
        preStm = c.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = preStm.executeQuery();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.print("erreur" + e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        requete.add(null);
        NomClient liste;
        while (rs.next()) {
            liste = new NomClient();
            liste.setNom(rs.getString(1));
            requete.add(liste);
            System.out.println("listenomclientfidelite, liste is : "+liste);
        }
        rs.close();
        preStm.close();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.print("errorlistenom" + e.getMessage());
    }

    Collections.sort(requete);
    return requete.toArray(new Object[0]);
}
```

nothing else to do than insert the returned ArrayList in a combobox.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't change the NomClient class so that it implements `Comparable<NomClient>`, meaning that you'd have to give it a `public int compareTo(NomClient o)` method, then use a `Comparator<NomClient>` in your sort method call. This is a class that you create that has one method, `public int compare(NomClient o1, NomClient o2)`, and that returns a -1, 0, or 1, depending on if o1 is functionally less than, equal to or greater than the o2 parameter. You would pass your Comparator instance as the 2nd paramter in your `Collections.sort(myCollection, myComparator)` method call.

Note that your problem has *nothing* to do with use of a Vector, and all to do with the NomClient class not implementing Comparable.

Comment: thanks, i wil try with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718383/java-class-implements-comparable and let you know the result.

Comment: it fail. there is something wrong with my implementation. i have updated first post according to the changes