# Arraylist comparison with string based conditions

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

Arraylist contains class model. Class has a parameter 'status' whose values would be 'open' , 'close' , ' upcoming '.

How to sort the arraylist based on ' status ' parameter i.e. 'open' should appear first, 'close' & 'upcoming' will be following to it respectively ?

Any help appreciated..

Comment: ready to help, pls try, post some code for us to start as well.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to implement the Comparable interface to your model class

Then implement the compareTo method with your compare logic.

And call `Collections.sort(yourModelList);` to make it.

You can find an example of implementing the Comparable interface [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718383/java-class-implements-comparable).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Unless the elements in your list have a notion of natural ordering, *do not* change `YourClass` to implement `Comparable<YourClass>`.

Instead, implement a `Comparator<YourClass>`, which is an entirely separate class:

```
class YourClassComparator implements Comparator<YourClass> {
  @Override
  public int compare(YourClass a, YourClass b) {
    // ... 
  }
}
```

and then pass an instance of this to `Collections.sort`:

```
Collections.sort(yourModelList, new YourClassComparator());
```