# Overriding compareTo(T t)

Tags: java, compareto, treeset

I did a class "People" which has a String name.
Now I want to compare two objects using TreeSet.

```
public class People<T> implements Comparable<T> {

    public TreeSet<People> treeSet;
    public String name;

    public People(String name)
    {
        treeSet =  new TreeSet();
this.name = name;
    }
```

.....

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(T y) {

        if(this.name.equals(y.name)) blablabla; //Here I get error 
    }
```

Error:

```
Cannot find symbol
symbol: variable name;
location: variable y of type T
where T is a type variable 
T extends Object declared in class OsobaSet
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Nothing tells the compiler, that _T_ type has a _name_ field .

Comment: I know and doesnt reall know how to fix it :/

Comment: I guess it should be `implements Comparable<People>` because that is what you want to compare. And then the compiler knows that People has a `name` Field ...

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3718515/982149

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generic type in `Comparable` interface stands for the type of objects that will be compared.

This is correct usage for your example:

```
public class People implements Comparable<People>
```

In this case method signature will be

```
@Override
public int compareTo(People y) {
    if (this.name.equals(y.name))  { ...
}
```