# Java Programming: How to use compareTo when comparing the names of the candidates in a text document

Tags: java, compareto

This method is used to compare the names of two candidates. Returns 0 if the name of this candidate is the same as the name of otherCan; returns < 0 if the name of this candidate is less then the name of otherCan; returns > 0 if the name of this candidate is greater than the name of otherCan.

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Candidate otherCan) {
        if(name = otherCan){
        return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(otherCan.getName());
    } else if(name < otherCan){
            return name < 0
        } else if(name > otherCan){
        return name > 0
        }
}
```

How do I compare them and what does return > 0 and < 0 mean?

Comment: why comparing name with otherCan by `<` or `>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718383/why-should-a-java-class-implement-comparable

Comment: `if(name = otherCan){` is wrong; it needs to be `if(name == otherCan){`. The single `=` is for assigning a value; the double is for comparing two things.

Comment: @Override
        public int compareTo(Candidate otherCan) {
            return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(otherCan.getName());
        }

Comment: does that meet the same postcondition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with this example.

```
    public int compareTo(Candidate otherCan) {
        if(name = otherCan){
```

As I pointed out in a comment, this must be `==`; otherwise, you're assigning the value of `otherCan` to `name`.

```
        return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(otherCan.getName());
```

If `name == otherCan` is `true`, then this call will *always* return `0`.

```
    } else if(name < otherCan){
            return name < 0
```

This line shouldn't compile because it's trying to return a `boolean` in a method that return an `int`.

```
        } else if(name > otherCan){
        return name > 0
```

Same as the previous note; this shouldn't compile.
            }
    }

This entire method is unnecessary. Just calling `name.compareToIgnoreCase(otherCan.getName())` is enough, as it will return `0` if the strings are equal, a negative number (not necessarily `-1`) if the first string comes before the second in sorted order, and a positive number if the second string should come first.

Comment: Thank you so much for confirmation. I was confused, but thank you so much for your help!!!