# A bubble sort for string. java

Tags: java

This is my first time to write a bubble sort for string and apparently i got many errors and the program could not run. I have no idea how to solve it. my code is:

```
import java.util.*;
    public class SortingRecord{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("How many people?");
            int n = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
            Record[] records = new Record[n];
            for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
                System.out.println("Inputting record["+i+"]:");
                System.out.print("Please input <First Name>:");
                String firstName = kb.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please input <Last Name>:");
                String lastName = kb.nextLine();
                records[i] = new Record(firstName, lastName);
            }
            sort(records);
            System.out.println("----------------");
            System.out.println("Print name in dictinary order:");
            for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
                System.out.println();
         } 

         public static void sort(Record[] records){
             if (records == null || records.length <= 1) return;
             int n = records.length;

             for(int i = 0; i< records.length ; i++){
                 for(int j = i+1 ; j< records.length; j++){
```

The symbol method compareTo(Record) couldn't be found.

```
                     if(records[j] .compareTo(records[i]) < 0){
```

It said Record cannot be converted to java.lang.String

```
                     String temp = records[i];
                     records[i] = records[j];
                     records[j] = temp;
                 }
              }
              System.out.println(records[i]);

             }
         }

    }

  class Record{
      public String firstName = "";
      public String lastName = "";
      public Record(String firstName, String lastName){
         this.firstName = firstName;
         this.lastName = lastName;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Ah, `Record` has no `compareTo` method ... did you forget to implement the `Comparable` interface?

Comment: Also, how is `Record` a `String`?

Comment: I just forllow the example on the Internet...and have no idea on it

Comment: The question is kinda obvious, but +1 for creative code formatting/error highlighting. :)

Comment: How do you want the `Record` sorted? By `firstName` or `lastName` or `firstName` then `lastName` or `lastName` then `firstNme`

Comment: firstName then lastName

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the obvious error:

```
if (records[j].compareTo(records[i]) < 0) {
```

`Record` does not provide any `compareTo` method, so you can't call it - it doesn't exist.

The next error:

```
String temp = records[i];
```

Is because `Record` is not a type of `String`, so it can't be assigned, the obvious solution is to use `Record` instead, something like...

```
Record temp = records[i];
records[i] = records[j];
records[j] = temp;
```

Okay, but how do we fix the `compareTo` issue?  This is more complicated than it might sound, while you implement the `Comparable` `interface` (or just implement the `compareTo` method directly), I'd not choose this path. Why?  Because you might want to change the way in which you sort the records and implementing the method would lock you into a single use case.

Instead, I'd use a `Comparator` passed into the method to do the actual comparison, providing the caller with the flexibility to change how the comparison actually works

```
public static void sort(Record[] records, Comparator<Record> comparator) {
    if (records == null || records.length <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    int n = records.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < records.length; j++) {
            if (comparator.compare(records[j], records[i]) < 0) {
                Record temp = records[i];
                records[i] = records[j];
                records[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(records[i]);

    }
}
```

Then you could do something like...

```
sort(records, new Comparator<Record>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Record o1, Record o2) {
        return o1.firstName.compareTo(o2.firstName);
    }
});
```

or

```
sort(records, new Comparator<Record>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Record o1, Record o2) {
        return o1.lastName.compareTo(o2.lastName);
    }
});
```

or even

```
sort(records, new Comparator<Record>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Record o1, Record o2) {
        int compare = o1.firstName.compareTo(o2.firstName);
        if (compare == 0) {
            compare = o1.lastName.compareTo(o2.lastName);
        }
        return compare;
    }
});
```

Or what ever else combination you might need to meet your requirements

I would suggest having a look at [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for more details

I should also point out that you could use `Collections` to also so the objects, but you'll need to convert it to `List` instead of array...

```
Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(records), new Comparator<Record>() {...});
```

> the program fail to output the name in dictionary order;(

Works fine for me...

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        Record[] records = new Record[] {
            new Record("B", "B"),
            new Record("C", "B"),
            new Record("D", "B"),
            new Record("A", "E"),
            new Record("A", "B"),
            new Record("A", "C"),
            new Record("A", "A"),
        };
        sort(records, new Comparator<Record>() {
                 @Override
                 public int compare(Record o1, Record o2) {
                     int compare = o1.firstName.compareTo(o2.firstName);
                     if (compare == 0) {
                         compare = o1.lastName.compareTo(o2.lastName);
                     }
                     return compare;
                 }
             });

        for (Record record : records) {
            System.out.println(record);
        }
    }

    public static void sort(Record[] records, Comparator<Record> comparator) {
        if (records == null || records.length <= 1) {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < records.length; j++) {
                if (comparator.compare(records[j], records[i]) < 0) {
                    Record temp = records[i];
                    records[i] = records[j];
                    records[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Record {

        public String firstName = "";
        public String lastName = "";

        public Record(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return firstName + " " + lastName;
        }


    }
}
```

Outputs

```
A A
A B
A C
A E
B B
C B
D B
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  but  I got an error on the line :  sort(records);                                                    Error: method sort in class SortingRecord cannot be applied to given types;
  required: Record[],java.util.Comparator<Record>
  found: Record[]
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Right, so, you didn't follow those three additional examples I wrote to demonstrate how you might be able to call the `sort` method?

Comment: Sorry that i overlooked it. but after i corrected the code, the program fail to output the name in dictionary order;(

Comment: Okay, after some quick test, it works fine for me, remove the `System.out.println` statement from `sort`, it might be intervering with your results

Comment: still failed, it displayed some weird words like                    Record@7d0d56b1
Record@32a63128

Comment: Print the properties of the `Record`, my example overrides the `toString` method because I'm lazy

Comment: sorry that i do not understand because i am a super beginner.... what is mean by the properties of the Record....  so sorry that i just learnt java in this semester and have no idea on it.

Comment: Use `System.out.println(record[i].firstName)` instead of `System.out.println(record[i])` or some such

Comment: thank you so much! my code could successfully output something that i want!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have **compareTo** method in Record class so that's why it's not found :) You probably should implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

As to "Record cannot be converted to java.lang.String", use **toString** method and you will be able to convert it, although you probably want to override **toString**.

Please also take a look at this example:
[Why should a Java class implement comparable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718383/why-should-a-java-class-implement-comparable)

Comment: *"use toString method and you will be able to convert it, although you probably want to override toString"* - But, no, you won't want to either, take a closer look at what the OP is trying to use the code for

Comment: I think he tries to convert his Record object to String in order to use compareTo on such converted objects, in such case I guess he could implement toString to do that job for him instead of writing his own compareTo.

Comment: No, they don't the original code was used to support sorting `String`s, the OP is trying to convert it to support their `Record` class

Comment: Well I'm not entirely convinced if OP exactly knows what he want so I just gave two ways of solving this problem. Of course in long term Comparable is the way to go although this error means what it means - toString was not called and that's why it couldn't be converted :)

Comment: You should ask some questions, the OP seems to have clarified there end goal in the comments