# how to implement comparator when compare function is used in the same class

Tags: java

If a class implements comparator, how can we define the compare function?

```
public int compare(classname c1, classname c2) {
    // c1 has to be this.how can we use it?
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? At the moment it's really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java class implements comparable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718383/java-class-implements-comparable)

Comment: Just read the comparator documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: Just think, you might want multiple comparators, so you will need multiple implementing classes. NB Comparable vs Comparator, they are slightly different

Comment: @reto Possible but not for certain. That describes Comparable and this  question is about Comparator. However I got to agree with T.J. though that it is not entirely clear what the question originator wants to achieve.

Comment: Well, you determine what constitutes "less than", "equal", and "greater than" for your class and you write the code to perform the appropriate tests.  It would be different for a BankAccount and a ZooAnimal.

Comment: @DanielBarbarian thanks. Relevant read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266827/when-to-use-comparable-vs-comparator

Answer (score 2):

You use the java Generics, built into the `Comparator` interface.

```
public class MyClass implements Comparator<MyClass>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int compare(classname c1, classname c2) {
    if (cl.something > c2.something)
        return 1;
    else if (c1.something == c2.something)
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Edit: with Comparable

```
public class classname implements Comparable<classname>{
    int something;

    public int compareTo(classname c2){
        if (this.something > c2.something)
            return 1;
        else if (this.something == c2.something)
            return 0;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: the c1 is the current object that is ..its THIS..how can we pass that as one of the arguments?

Comment: In that case you should use compareTo() and make the class Comparable. See my edit