# How to start two threads at "exactly" the same time

Tags: java, multithreading

The threads should start at same split second. I understand, if you do `thread1.start()`, it will take some milliseconds before the next execution of `thread2.start()`.

Is it even possible or impossible?

Comment: Split second is a very long time at GHz speeds.

Comment: No need to downvote so intensely.  Not everyone understands threading-related nondeterminism, and we all have to start somewhere.

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes. Synchronizing between threads is a very common necessity. Yes in java you can't have them executing exactly in parallel (which, on other platform can be a very valid requirement btw), but from time to time it is very common that you need to synchronize their action. That's why the jdk has classes for  doing that. Maybe the wording was not accurate, but hell if he'd know that, he wouldn't have asked the question..

Comment: well, I guess I understand all your anger. It was a question asked to me in an interview...probably was a trick Q. But, I just got confused and wanted to confirm it. that's why I asked if it was even possible.

Comment: @javaguy - not a "trick" question.  Rather a question chosen to see how well you really understand multi-threaded programming in general ... as well in the Java case.

Comment: @javaguy Semantically speaking, `CyclicBarrier` is the sort of synchronization mechanism that can start off two threads running "at the same time" (again, semantically speaking), avoiding the cost of Thread creation in the timing.

Physically speaking, hardware limitation and context switching (and also Physics) dictates such a notion (if to be taken literally) is ridiculous.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

To start the threads at exactly the same time (at least as good as possible), you can use a [CyclicBarrier](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html):

```
// We want to start just 2 threads at the same time, but let's control that 
// timing from the main thread. That's why we have 3 "parties" instead of 2.
final CyclicBarrier gate = new CyclicBarrier(3);

Thread t1 = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        gate.await();
        //do stuff    
    }};
Thread t2 = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        gate.await();
        //do stuff    
    }};

t1.start();
t2.start();

// At this point, t1 and t2 are blocking on the gate. 
// Since we gave "3" as the argument, gate is not opened yet.
// Now if we block on the gate from the main thread, it will open
// and all threads will start to do stuff!

gate.await();
System.out.println("all threads started");
```

This doesn't have to be a `CyclicBarrier`, you could also use a `CountDownLatch` or even a lock.

This still can't make sure that they are started *exactly* at the same time on standard JVMs, but you can get pretty close. Getting pretty close is still useful when you do for example performance tests. E.g., if you are trying to measure throughput of a data structure with different number of threads hitting it, you want to use this kind of construct to get the most accurate result possible.

On other platforms, starting threads *exactly* can be a very valid requirement btw.

Comment: +1 nice thinking ;-) Although of course it doesn't make the threads start at _exactly_ the same time in real time (at least not on a single-core chip, and not guaranteed even on a multi-core chip), but I can't think of any way to do better.

Comment: Will this hook into environment specific wait handles?

Comment: @Santa - The Win32 API for example offers different primitives. One useful type is the manual reset event returned when you call `CreateEvent`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686364%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Zwei - Well, whatever it is, this is the answer I would have posted had I been a Java guru.

Comment: +1 I remember doing the barrier problem in my OS class for several distributed nodes in C. It was a mess.

Comment: The first example provided in the [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) might give the impression of a synchronized start. That is not true but could easily be patched (see my own [blog post](http://blog.martinandersson.com/javas-countdownlatch-javadoc-is-flawed/) about it).

Comment: @MartinAndersson: If I understand you correctly, you are talking about the delay in readying the threads before they block on the latch. I see how that can be a problem. I guess it's a more general problem rather than specific to CountDownLatch. In the real world, people would probably do warm ups to cope with other factors like JIT compilation, which would also solve this problem.

Comment: @EnnoShioji, I really wonder if we put high number of threads lets say 10,000 threads would it execute at the same time or not?

Comment: @Halim: It won't, at that number you'll be having lots of context switching which drags down the whole performance and you'll see higher variance (at least on today's common hardwares..).

Comment: @EnnoShioji. Thanks. I'm thinking the same. But I have requirements to test 10k threads parallel/simultaneously/at the same time not concurrently for performance testing. How to achieve that? Any idea?

Comment: @Halim: Depends on what you want to do. If you want to make lots of concurrent network calls for example, you can use non blocking IO.

Comment: If you have 2 threads, do you could make it work with gate = new CyclicBarrier(2) ? the second await() call would trigger the both threads

Comment: This solution depends on knowing the number of threads. The solution by @aNish using a `CountDownLatch` is better in this respect, as it is simpler and less prone to off-by-one errors or more resilient to change. Also, there is nothing ‘cyclic’ here, so the use of a `CyclicBarrier` is all but intuitive.

Answer (score 20):

You could use a CountDownLatch for this.
Please find below a sample.
Though t1 and t2 are started, these threads keep waiting till the main thread counts down the latch. The number of countdowns required is mentioned in the constructor. Countdown latch can also be used to wait for threads to finish execution so that the main thread can proceed further(the reverse case). This class was included since Java 1.5.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;


public class ThreadExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        MyThread t1 = new MyThread(latch);
        MyThread t2 = new MyThread(latch);
        new Thread(t1).start();
        new Thread(t2).start();
        //Do whatever you want
        latch.countDown();          //This will inform all the threads to start
        //Continue to do whatever
    }
}

class MyThread implements Runnable
{
    CountDownLatch latch;
    public MyThread(CountDownLatch latch) 
    {
        this.latch = latch;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        try 
        {
            latch.await();          //The thread keeps waiting till it is informed
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Do the actual thing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

It is not possible, at least on a single core computer. But why do you want that? Even if you were able to start two threads at exactly the same second, they will progress differently because scheduling is not in your control.

Edit: (In response to some of the comments) It is a perfectly valid requirement to *synchronize the state or progress* of multiple threads and `CyclicBarrier` is a great tool. I answered the question whether it is possible to start multiple threads *at exactly the same time*. `CyclicBarrier` will guarantee that the threads proceed when they are exactly at the desired state but it doesn't guarantee that they will start or resume at *exactly* the same time, although it might be pretty close. There's no mention of synchronization needs in the question.

Comment: You can get pretty darn close though. It all depends on the synchronization techniques you use *and of course having more than 1 cpu or core.*

Comment: The idea is that this is wrong-headed approach and should not be necessary in any not-hard-real-time environment, not that it's "pretty close".

Comment: Even in a very simple performance test for modules, synchronizing the "start of processing" is very much necessary to obtain valid data.. And damn close is much preferable in such cases.

Comment: It is *also* impossible because Java thread scheduling does not give you millisecond accuracy.

Comment: @Nikolai - I totally agree. And the OP doesn't want darn close. OP wants *same split second*

Comment: @Zwei - you can probably get "damn close" most of the time on an otherwise idle machine.  But if you need it all of the time, you need to program in a language like C, on a machine with hard realtime support in the OS.  Consider also that the JVM might be running a full GC at the "split second" you want to start your threads.

Comment: @Stephen - Exactly. I think even sleep is not *guaranteed* to be accurate down to a millisecond.

Comment: @Stephen: Yes, I agree. But there is still value in doing this because at least you can prevent having full GC between the start of t1/t2, etc. That kind of preparation is necessary to make performance data as reliable as possible. But then again I agree that we should be warning the OP about your point.. So +1 for the answer!

Comment: It is a perfectly valid synchronization problem. Threads need to initialize some data, make sure that no one goes into a critical region without proper validation. And the fact that CyclicBerrier is included in javas concurrent package means that this an important problem.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy: you’re describing the main intent of `CyclicBarrier`, which, after all, is not to “start threads at ‘exactly’ the same time” but to ensure that *no thread starts before a certain event*. Which thankfully doesn’t require the guaranty that each thread proceeds at exactly the same time, as no such guaranty exists.

Answer (score 7):

1. As I understand it, the JVM mostly delegates this stuff to the operating system.  So the answer will be OS-specific.
2. It is clearly impossible on a single-processor machines.
3. It is more complicated with respect to a multi-processor machine.  According to the [Relativity of simultaneity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity), "it is impossible to say in an absolute sense whether two events occur at the same time if those events are separated in space."  No matter how close your processors are, they are separated in space.

   1. If you can accept relative simultaneity, then it is probably easier just to simulate it using techniques discussed in other responses.

Comment: …and even if we assume a simultaneous start, each thread has its own timeline, all of them being *concurrent*, but not necessarily parallel, so whatever someone assumes about the simultaneity of threads can (will) be void in the next nanosecond (of whichever timeline)…

Answer (score -1):

I've checked proposed answers and I've noticed that using classic spin locks works better when starting threads at the "same moment" and success rate for threads collisions is better.

```
AtomicInteger startedThreadsCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
AtomicBoolean spinLock = new AtomicBoolean(true);


void collide(Runnable runnable) {

    for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++) {
      executor.execute(() -> decorate(runnable));
    }

    while (startedThreadsCount.get() < threadsCount)
      ;

    spinLock.set(false);
}

void decorate(Runnable runnable) {

    startedThreadsCount.incrementAndGet();

    while (startedThreadsCount.get() < threadsCount)
      ;

    while (spinLock.get())
      ;

     runnable.run();
  }
```

I've created [threads-collider](https://github.com/stawirej/threads-collider) library which tries to run threads at "exactly" the same time to expose concurrency issues e.g. in simple unit testing.