# How to start multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using the Java Thread class and given a user input parameter k 
creating k Thread like `MyThread myThread[] = new MyThread [k];`
Now one way to start a thread is to make a for loop and do `.start()` on each 
thread instance. But I guess that won't start it simultaneously. Is there any way 
to do that? Or a better alternative to using a for loop to start all the threads?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start two threads at "exactly" the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376586/how-to-start-two-threads-at-exactly-the-same-time)

Comment: Why exactly do you want to start the threads 'simultaneously'?

Comment: Literally you can't get them to start simultaneously.  Indeed, if there are more threads than you have cores (or hyperthreads) then they can't run simultaneously.  If your app design replies on being able to do that kind of thing, it is probably not implementable in any programming language whose implementation uses native threads (i.e. multiple cores).

Comment: So apart from using the trick used in another StackOverflow posts by using countdownlatch. Are there any disadvantages of starting them in for loop one by one?