# How can i pass a list of objects (any object), through bundle, from activity A to Activity B?

Tags: android

This is on the android platform, i have a list of objects of type (FitItem), and i want pass the list from my activity A to another activity B, and on the activity B i want get the list of objects again

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent yourIntent = new Intent(activityA.this, activityB.class);
Bundle yourBundle = new Bundle();
yourBundle.putString("name", value);
yourIntent.putExtras(yourBundle);
startActivity(yourIntent);
```

And you get the value in the next `Activity` (in your `onCreate()`):

```
Bundle yourBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String s = yourBundle.getString("name");
```

This example is passing a `String`, but you should be able to grasp how to use it for other objects.

Answer (score 1):

**For custom classes:**
You will have to have your `FitItem` class implements [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Then in Activity A, from an `Intent` object, use [putParcelableArrayListExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29) to pass the list of `FitItem` to Activity B and in your Activity B, use [getParcelableArrayListExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve the list of `FitItem`

If you want to pass list of String, Integer, Float ..., refer to bschultz post

Answer (score 1):

You must serialize your object.

"Seriawhat?"

Ok, first things first: [What is object serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization)

"Got it, but how do I do that?"

You can use Parcelable (more code, but faster) or Serializable (less code, but slower). 
[Parcelable vs Serializable](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable).

"Save me some time, **show me the code**!"

Ok, if you'll use **Parcelable**, see [this](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/05/android-parcelable-tutorial-list-class.html).

And if you'll use **Serializable**, see [this](http://www.easyinfogeek.com/2014/01/android-tutorial-two-methods-of-passing.html) and/or [this](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/passing-objects-between-activities.html).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If they're if the object is serializable, just add them as extras to the intent. I think something like this:

```
// in Activity A, when starting Activity B
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExra("fitItemList", fitItemList);
startActivity(i);

// in Activity B (onCreate)
ArrayList<FitItem> fitItemList = savedInstanceState.getSerializableExtra("fitItemList");
```

edit:
Just like bschultz already posted :)

Answer (score 0):

Implements Serializable in model class. Then you can pass model class using bundle/intent.