# ASP.NET: Is it possible to keep complex object such as list<> is the session?

Tags: asp.net, session-state

ASP.NET: Is it possible to keep complex object such as `List<object>` is the session? If yes, how to do so? I'm trying to keep a list in the session, but I'm being told that I cannot convert that List to a string.

## EDIT

```
[Serializable]
public class Client
{
        public string ClientType { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public string SubClientName { get; set; }
        public string Project { get; set; }
        public string Service { get; set; }
        public string Activity { get; set; }
}
List<Client> ListOfClients;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
        ListOfClients = new List<Client> { new Client()}; 
        Session["ListOfClients"] = ListOfClients;//This is where the error occurs
                                                 //Cannot convert List<Client> to string... 
     }  
}
```

There are many operations to execute, but the idea is to keep whatever is in the list of clients in the session.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm pretty sure anything that is `Serializable` can be stored in a session.  Would you mind posting your code?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that Client does not implement `ISerializable` and is therefore not serializable for some reason.  Trying adding the `[Serializable]` attribute to your class.

Comment: I've added [serializable], but still get the same error, see the code I'm using

Comment: Post your full `Client` implementation, in case there is something inside it we're not seeing.

Comment: There are just a bunch of string as the ones you see there, i.e. Address, street, ...see edits

Comment: I just tried this code verbatim in my own Web Application project.  It worked great with no exception.

Comment: Do you have some other thing in scope called Session? Like some Page member variable or similar? Or some own custom class/user control called Session? Does the error come at runtime or compile time?

Comment: the error happens at compile time. Also, besides there are some other sessions objects, but none of them has the same name.

Comment: Show Page directive of this page. It's placed at first line of aspx file

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can store any [serializable object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/447898/370103) into a session variable. For example:

```
List<string> list;

Session["list"] = list;
```

Then to return the value:

```
List<string> list = (List<string>)Session["list"];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can store anything in the session object as long as [session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) is in `InProc` mode.

Otherwise what you store has to be serialisable.

Note that the type of what you store is `object`, so you cast the reference that you get back:

```
ListOfClients = Session["ListOfClients"] as List<Client>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote in a comment that the error happens when compiling as opposed to at runtime, I suspect that you have some other object called `Session` that masks the `Page.Session`.

Try to hover your mouse over the Session text in Visual Studio. The tooltip should show you that Session is of type

```
System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState
```

If it's showing something else, you need to search both your markup (.aspx file) and code behind file to see if you have declared something else with the name/id `Session` and then change that name/id.