# Invoke a method of an Object in the Heap of a jvm

Tags: java, jvm

Is it possible to get an Object from the Heap in a JVM and call a method on it.

Lets say I have this:

```
public class TestObjectOnHeap {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

And I created a web application that instantiated the class like this

```
TestObjectOnHeap obj = new TestObjectOnHeap();
obj.setName("created in webapp");
```

Then I wanted to create a different application (maybe via a javaagent?) that read that value and printed `"created in webapp"`

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you talking about trying to acquire a new reference to an otherwise completely unknown object that exists on the JVM's heap?

Comment: I will know the name and type of the Object in the Heap.  But I actually want to get the value of name from that object after it was created by a totally different application.  
So I hope to be able to do this:
 `TestObjectOnHeap obj = someMagicToGetObjectFromHeap();
 Assert.equals("created in webapp", obj.getName());
 `

Comment: What you're talking about is called a *forged reference* and would completely break the JVM security model if permitted.

Comment: it might be possible with `sun.misc.Unsafe`, but that's basically playing a game of chicken against the VM. And the VM has no brakes.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. You'd have to pass it to the other program, or make it available to the other program through a service, or save it to a database where the other program could find it. In any case, it's going to involve some kind of [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization).