# Could anyone tell me whats use of implements interface which extended with "Serializable" interface with example?

Tags: java, interface, serializable

Interface with serializable implements?

```
 public interface SearchCriteria extends Serializable {}
```

class which implements a interface which doesnt have method initilization 
just a extented by "Serializable" interface

```
  public class AbstractSearchCriteria implements SearchCriteria
 {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private PageCriteria pageCriteria;

public AbstractSearchCriteria()
{
    super();
}

public PageCriteria getPageCriteria()
{
    return pageCriteria;
}

public void setPageCriteria(PageCriteria pageCriteria)
{
    this.pageCriteria = pageCriteria;
}}
```

Comment: It's a marker interface; perhaps something in your code base uses it.

Comment: Please express your question in standard English.

Answer (score 1):

serialization is the process of translating data structures or object state into a format that can be stored.

Serializable is a marker interface
serializable is a special interface that specifies that class is serialiazable. It's special in that unlike a normal interface it does not define any methods that must be implemented: it is simply marking the class as serializable.

more here [What is object serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization)

Answer (score 1):

In short:

You extended `Serializable` interface in `SearchCriteria` interface. All classes that implement the `SearchCriteria` interface, will also be implementing `Serializable` interface by default.

For more detailed info check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).