# Convert hash table to byte array

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a hash table and I want to send it through by Datagram Socket.
So to do this I need to have a byte array. 
How can I convert my hash table to a byte array?
I've ignore filling a hash table
I've tried do this by this way:

```
    Hashtable<String, String> valueNick = new Hashtable<>();
    nickStr = valueNick.toString();
    byte[] bufferNick = nickStr.getBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferNick.length; i++) {
             System.out.print(bufferNick[i] + " ");
        }
```

But nothing has been printed.
                Thanks very much for any help or advise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is object serialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization)

Comment: Have you added any thing in the Hashtable?

Comment: @Ankushsoni Yes, I just ignored it.

Comment: @dotvav Maybe but I don't want to save it into a file.

Comment: @James: which Jdk version are you using?

Comment: You can always try a longer solution , by iterating through the entry set of the hashtable and adding the values to your byte array as you go along , this  should solve your problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code(added value in it)

```
Hashtable<String, String> valueNick = new Hashtable<>();    
    valueNick.put("name", "Ankush");
    valueNick.put("lastName", "Soni");
        String nickStr = valueNick.toString();
        byte[] bufferNick = nickStr.getBytes();
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferNick.length; i++) {
                 System.out.print(bufferNick[i] + " ");
            }   }
```

It is printing below output:

> 123 108 97 115 116 78 97 109 101 61 83 111 110 105 44 32 110 97 109
>   101 61 65 110 107 117 115 104 125

**Edit:** With the empty Hashtable also I am able to print the byte data which is

> 123 125

Comment: My hash table has value, I just ignored it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider checking out [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) for this purpose

Check out this [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077539/learn-java/java-tip-40--object-transport-via-datagram-packets.html) for an example and explanation

The following is an example to serialize the table:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(5000);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(byteStream));

// writes the object into a bytestream
oos.writeObject(valueNick);
oos.close();

byte[] sendBuf = byteStream.toByteArray();
// now send the sendBuf via a Datagram Socket
```

The following is an example to read the object:

```
ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(recvBuf);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(byteStream));
Hashtable<String, String> msg = (Hashtable<String, String>) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

Comment: plus1 Since this may be the right way to go, consider to extend the answer a little more with an example. Thanks