# NotSerializableException wiht HashMap serialize

Tags: java

I have a problem with serialize...I test this methods separate from class and  worked correctly! But when I use this class get `NotSerializableException`

Code:
Property that must to be serialize:
`public ArrayList<User> users;`

This property is in `UserManage` class

This method for reading from database file:

```
public void readFromDataBaseFile(){
    File database=new File(this.saveUsersObject+"\\"+"Database.txt");
    if(!database.exists()){
        System.out.println("Exception:FileNotExist");
    }
    else{
        HashMap<String,Object> Data=(HashMap<String,Object>)FileHandler.readObjectInFile(database);
        this.users= (ArrayList) Data.get("users");
    }
}
```

And this method for writing to database file:

```
public void writeToDataBaseFile(){
    File database=new File(this.saveUsersObject+"\\"+"Database.txt");
    if(!database.exists()) {
        File parent=database.getParentFile();
        parent.mkdirs();
    }
    HashMap<String,Object> Data=allOfUsersToHashMap();
    if(Data.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("DataBase HashMap Is Empty!");

    }
    else{
        FileHandler.writeObjectInFile(Data,database);
    }
}
```

Above method are in class `UserManage`.

below method is a helper method to writing an  object in a file:

1. `boolean writeObjectInFile(Object obj,File file)`:

```
public static boolean writeObjectInFile(Object obj,File file){
    String Path=file.getAbsolutePath();
    if(file.exists()){
        System.out.println("Object File Was Deleted!!");
        file.delete();
    }
    else{
        try
        {

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(Path);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(obj);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved To :"+file.getPath());
            return true;
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

And below method is a helper method to reading an  object from a file:

2. `Object readObjectInFile(File file)`:

```
 public static Object readObjectInFile(File file) {
    Object obj=null;
    if(file.isFile()){
        try
        {

            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            obj=in.readObject();
            fileIn.close();
            in.close();
            System.out.printf("DeSerialized data is Done From:"+file.getPath());
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("returned null :\\");
        System.out.println("Enter Address Of A File Not Folder Or Another! :\\");
    }
    return obj;
}
```

method `allOfUsersToHashMap()` in class `UserManage`:

```
public HashMap<String,Object> allOfUsersToHashMap(){
    HashMap<String,Object> Userdatabase=new HashMap<>();
    Userdatabase.put("users",this.users);
    return Userdatabase;
}
```

I must say when `ArrayList<User> user` is null this method worked correctly but when has user dont work!

Comment: What's the definition of the `User` class? It has to be `Serializable` to work with the standard serialization functionality.

Comment: Can you check whether User class is Serializable I.e., implementing Serializable interface?

Comment: Do you think when I use `HashMap` need to serialize `User`?? @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu @birryree

Comment: @MEER yes.  `User` still needs to be serializable.

Comment: I just add This `implements Serializable ` to class `User` but got that error again..Is it mistake by this work? @Louis Wasserman

Comment: @MEER Show us the complete error message.  (It'll tell you what class it couldn't serialize.)

Comment: `java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: Client.User`@LouisWasserman

Comment: Just By adding `implements Serializable ` keyword to class name?@MadhusudanaReddySunnapu

Comment: I add `implements Serializable` to `User` class but it not work...search in google but not found any method that must be implement from this interface @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu  @Louis Wasserman..I am new in java :)

Comment: Can you post the User class as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328413/implements-serializable-in-all-of-classes-but-get-notserializableexception @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the User class doesn't implement the Serializable interface, the ArrayList won't be able to be serialized.  See the JavaDoc for Serializable for implementation details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: But I don't Use this class for serialize and first put this class to a hash map and then pass this `HashMap` to another static method in another class then serialize@upcrob

Comment: `HashMap` is serializable! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207376/is-hashtable-hashmap-serializable-in-java

Comment: @MEER: That doesn't matter.  `HashMap` is serializable, sure, but if a single object in the `HashMap` isn't serializable, then it won't work.  `User` still has to be serializable.

Comment: HashMap is Serializable as well, but the objects it (or ArrayList) contains are not necessarily Serializable.  If you want to serialize the ArrayList<User> variable, User must be Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

Does your `User` POJO meets all the requisites to be serialized?

Check this previous question: [What is object serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization)