# Implements serializable in all of classes but get NotSerializableException

Tags: java

I serialize all of my class but get exception...anyone can say which one of class properties cause this problem?

1-

```
    public class UserManage  {
       public ArrayList<User> users=null;
```

2-

```
public class User implements java.io.Serializable      {
    private String firstName;
    private ArrayList<Repository> userRepositories=null;
```

3-

```
public class Repository implements java.io.Serializable {
    public  String parentPathOfAllRepositories="D:\\TestOfJava";
    private ArrayList<String> contributorsID=null;
    private String ParentDefaultPath=null;
    private HashMap<File,String> LockListFile=null;
    private HashMap<File,String> FileHashlist=null;
    private String VersionHolderFolderPath=null;

    private HashMap<HashMap<File,String>,HashMap<Date,String>> VersionsList=null;
```

I must say that `ArrayList<User>` in class `UserManage` must be serialize to a file

[Update]:Exception Message:`java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: Client.User`

Comment: update your exception message also.

Comment: Show us the exception message.

Comment: @LouisWasserman.In my Last post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319544/notserializableexception-wiht-hashmap-serialize?noredirect=1#comment56383736_34319544 you said me to serialize.but i serialize and got this exception again

Comment: I do not see any non-serializable classes in the `User` class, but I would either remove all fields and add them one by one again to see which one is causing the issue or put `transient` in front of all fields and then remove it one by one while executing the serialization after each step. Also, ideally provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the issue.