# java.io.NotSerializableException: weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessLocalObject

Tags: java, weblogic

I installed a Weblogic 12C cluster with two servers. When i start the servers everything works fine with the application but at the first Loggin into the application i can see this exception in the server log.

```
 <BEA-000126 <All session objects should be serializable to replicate. Check the objects in the session. Failed to replicate a non-serializable object.
```

java.ri.arshalException: failed to arshal update(Lweblogic.cluster.replication.ROID;ILjava.io.Serializable;Ljava.lang.Object;); nested exception is:
         java.io.NotSerializableException: weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessLocalObject
         at weblogic.rjv.BasicOutboundRequest.arshalArgs(BasicOutboundRequest.java:92)
         at weblogic.ri.internal.BasicReoteRef.invoke(BasicReoteRef.java:301)
         at weblogic.cluster.replication.ANReplicationanager_12130_WLStub.update(Unknown Source)
         at sun.reflect.NativeethodAccessorIpl.invoke0(Native ethod)
         at sun.reflect.NativeethodAccessorIpl.invoke(NativeethodAccessorIpl.java:62)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingethodAccessorIpl.invoke(DelegatingethodAccessorIpl.java:43)
         at java.lang.reflect.ethod.invoke(ethod.java:497)
         at weblogic.cluster.replication.SecureReplicationInvocationHandler$ReplicationServicesInvocationAction.run(SecureReplicationInvocationHandler.java:194)
         at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
         at weblogic.security.service.Securityanager.runAs(Securityanager.java:120)
         at weblogic.cluster.replication.SecureReplicationInvocationHandler.invoke(SecureReplicationInvocationHandler.java:164)
         at co.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.update(Unknown Source)
         at weblogic.cluster.replication.Replicationanager.sendUpdateRequestToSecondary(Replicationanager.java:763)
         at weblogic.cluster.replication.Replicationanager.updateSecondary(Replicationanager.java:678)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.ReplicatedSessionData._syncSession(ReplicatedSessionData.java:599)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.ReplicatedSessionData.syncSession(ReplicatedSessionData.java:563)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext.sync(SessionContext.java:148)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestIpl$SessionHelper.syncSession(ServletRequestIpl.java:3258)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestIpl$SessionHelper.syncSessions(ServletRequestIpl.java:3236)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestIpl$SessionHelper.syncSession(ServletRequestIpl.java:3224)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseIpl$1.run(ServletResponseIpl.java:1597)
         at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
         at weblogic.security.service.Securityanager.runAs(Securityanager.java:120)
         at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseIpl.send(ServletResponseIpl.java:1593)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestIpl.run(ServletRequestIpl.java:1582)
         at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderIpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderIpl.java:255)
         at java.io.ObjectOutputStrea.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStrea.java:1509)
         at java.io.ObjectOutputStrea.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStrea.java:1432)
         at java.io.ObjectOutputStrea.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStrea.java:1178)
         at java.io.ObjectOutputStrea.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStrea.java:1548)
         at java.io.ObjectOutputStrea.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStrea.java:1509)
         at java.io.ObjectOutputStrea.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStrea.java:1432)
         at java.io.ObjectOutputStrea.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStrea.java:1178)
         at java.io.ObjectOutputStrea.writeObject(ObjectOutputStrea.java:348)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.ReplicatedSessionChange.writeExternal(ReplicatedSessionChange.java:181)
         at java.io.ObjectOutputStrea.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStrea.java:1459)
         at java.io.ObjectOutputStrea.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStrea.java:1430)
         at java.io.ObjectOutputStrea.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStrea.java:1178)
         at java.io.ObjectOutputStrea.writeObject(ObjectOutputStrea.java:348)
         at weblogic.rjv.sgAbbrevOutputStrea.writeObject(sgAbbrevOutputStrea.java:627)
         at weblogic.rjv.sgAbbrevOutputStrea.writeObjectWL(sgAbbrevOutputStrea.java:618)
         at weblogic.ri.internal.ObjectIO.writeObject(ObjectIO.java:38)
         at weblogic.rjv.BasicOutboundRequest.arshalArgs(BasicOutboundRequest.java:88)
         at weblogic.ri.internal.BasicReoteRef.invoke(BasicReoteRef.java:301)
         at weblogic.cluster.replication.ANReplicationanager_12130_WLStub.update(Unknown Source)
         at sun.reflect.NativeethodAccessorIpl.invoke0(Native ethod)
         at sun.reflect.NativeethodAccessorIpl.invoke(NativeethodAccessorIpl.java:62)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingethodAccessorIpl.invoke(DelegatingethodAccessorIpl.java:43)
         at java.lang.reflect.ethod.invoke(ethod.java:497)
         at weblogic.cluster.replication.SecureReplicationInvocationHandler$ReplicationServicesInvocationAction.run(SecureReplicationInvocationHandler.java:194)
         at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
         at weblogic.security.service.Securityanager.runAs(Securityanager.java:120)
         at weblogic.cluster.replication.SecureReplicationInvocationHandler.invoke(SecureReplicationInvocationHandler.java:164)
         at co.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.update(Unknown Source)
         at weblogic.cluster.replication.Replicationanager.sendUpdateRequestToSecondary(Replicationanager.java:763)
         at weblogic.cluster.replication.Replicationanager.updateSecondary(Replicationanager.java:678)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.ReplicatedSessionData._syncSession(ReplicatedSessionData.java:599)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.ReplicatedSessionData.syncSession(ReplicatedSessionData.java:563)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext.sync(SessionContext.java:148)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestIpl$SessionHelper.syncSession(ServletRequestIpl.java:3258)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestIpl$SessionHelper.syncSessions(ServletRequestIpl.java:3236)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestIpl$SessionHelper.syncSession(ServletRequestIpl.java:3224)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseIpl$1.run(ServletResponseIpl.java:1597)
         at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext.sync(SessionContext.java:148)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestIpl$SessionHelper.syncSession(ServletRequestIpl.java:3258)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestIpl$SessionHelper.syncSessions(ServletRequestIpl.java:3236)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestIpl$SessionHelper.syncSession(ServletRequestIpl.java:3224)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseIpl$1.run(ServletResponseIpl.java:1597)
         at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
         at weblogic.security.service.Securityanager.runAs(Securityanager.java:120)
         at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseIpl.send(ServletResponseIpl.java:1593)
         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestIpl.run(ServletRequestIpl.java:1582)
         at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderIpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderIpl.java:255)
         at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
         at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

The application dont use EJB containers. Any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this exception is thrown when an object is being send or received while not being serialisable.
This means that the class where the object was created from is not implementing the "serializable" interface. I don't know if you have any access to the code of the server (or client).
To be more clear of what serialisation does see this older post : [What is object serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization)