# Downloading a file from spring controllers NotSerializableException

Tags: java, spring, file, model-view-controller, download

I am using Spring Frame work 3.05 and i wanted download files using same framework.After googling i found answer in this stack overflow link .

[Downloading a file from spring controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers)

in the above link -> Scott Carlson -
Answer

But if i try to do as suggested in the above link. I am getting following Error :

" **Error while writing to output stream due to :java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource** "

My code looks Like :

```
    FileSystemResource fsr =  new FileSystemResource(path);         

    try
    {

        OutputStream outstr = res.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outstr);
        oos.writeObject(fsr);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        log4log.error("Error while writing to output stream due to :"+e.toString());
        return null;
    }
```

Please Help me out...

Comment: you can not serialise the Stream itselb. You have to read the data from strem and then you can serialize it.

Comment: Scott Carlson's answer doesn't do, at all, what you're doing in your code. Just read it again.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to copy the contents your `FileSystemResource` into the response's `Outputstream`:

```
InputStream in = fsr.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(in, out);
```

What you were trying to do in your code is actually trying to [serialize an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization) into the output stream of the response.

Comment: The image file downloading in browser.But when i try download in nodejs server ,its getting corrupted.Actuly file size of downloaded file is 1.8Mb insted of 1 Mb. How to solve this...