# Storing a double array in an external file and reading it

Tags: java

I'm writting some code that needs to store some data like this:

```
double[] VERTS = {
            0.000000, -7.350000, 21.750000,
            0.000000, -9.145293, 21.750000
}
```

However, I want the double[] VERTS array to be in an external file. Is this possible?

EDIT: And how can I read it back?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: arrays are stored in memory . to put them in a file you need `Serialization`

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There are many ways to do so.

Comment: Ask google. You will have everything. :)

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=34789) in order to learn how to do it. Also, mind what @Ramanlfc has said - the [concept](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization) of [Serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

Answer (score 5):

This is what [DataOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) # [writeDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeDouble-double-) does.

```
new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file.txt")).writeDouble(1.02d);
```

A Java >= 7 [buffered](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) solution which will take care of [closing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) resources using a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block :

```
try (DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file.txt")))) {
    for (double vert : VERTS) {
        os.writeDouble(vert);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are talking about is called `serialization` in Java.

Use `ObjectOutputStream` to write an object into a file:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);   
    oos.writeObject(obj); // write array obj to ObjectOutputStream
    oos.close(); 
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ObjectOutputStream`

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

double[] VERTS = {
                0.000000, -7.350000, 21.750000,
                0.000000, -9.145293, 21.750000
        };

        oos.writeObject(VERTS);
        oos.close();
```