# Importance of serialization

Tags: java, serialization

This might look simple but i haven't got satisfying answer anywhere.

**Why do we need Serialization ?**

Answer I found everywhere is like -

> To convert object in byte stream and to store in DB.

But my question is - *can't we do it without using serialization?
If not how we are storing the data in DB?*

Please explain me clearly, if possible provide me an example

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is not to store objects in a database.

It's to convert an object into a stream of bytes. That stream of bytes can be used indeed to store it into a database, but it can also be used to save it into a file or send it through a socket ([here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/448233/20654)).

> *Can't we do it without using serialization?*

Absolutely, actually it's very rare to use serialization to store data in a database. Most of the times (I would say 99%) is using [JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jdbc/info) mainly through an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tool such as Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for response @OscarRyz, But my question is Even if i dont use serialization, Data/Object will be transferred in byte stream right? Then why serialization is important?

Comment: No, it won't be transferred into byte stream. There will be an in memory representation of the object, but that's not a "serial" version. That is, when you "serialize" an object, you put it one byte after another a linear sequence. Objects in memory are not layout like this and the actual representation is abstracted away from the user. Object serialization can be used when there's a need to represent the object into a stream of bytes. In some other cases you can use another data interchange format (json, xml, yaml, comma separated values) Serialization is just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Because data is transferred as byte stream across the network, you cannot put your `Object` inside the wire.

In case of JDBC - sort of its own serialization performed by the `Driver` itself in appropriate format.

In general, this is not about programming, but general network structure.

The data traverses the following path:

- Application layer
- Transport layer
- Internet layer
- Link layer

At the last point it converted to the byte stream and physically crosses the network.

Comment: You don't serialize anything when using JDBC, with JDBC you explicitly say: "For this table field, use this value" so you deconstruct the object manually.