# How to add different subclass object types from text file to an array list of type parent class?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, serialization, file-io

I was given an assignment to create a Employee parent class with several extended classes (manager, salaried employee etc.) I have completed the assignment but, I wanted to see if I could go a step further and attempt to read and add objects to a text file with different object types so that I can save objects created from the last time the program ran. This is proving a bit more tricky than reading objects of the same type from a text file since the manager, salaried employee and hourly employee classes that extend from the employee parent class have different constructor parameters. I have done a bit of research and came across serialization but am still a tad confused.

Current constructors are:
- Employee (String name,String title, int id)
- Manager(String name,String title, int id,double salary, double bonus)
- SalariedEmployee(String name,String title, int id,double salary)
- HourlyEmployee(String name,String title, int id,double wage, double
  hours)

A sample of the text file I'd like to read and initialize an ArrayList from:

Morgan Lee; Manager; 109; 120000; 20

Harry N; Salaried Employee; 110; 89000

Lee Ann M; Hourly Employee; 111; 18; 40

Recap: I'd like to read and add different object types from a text file into an ArrayList. I've managed to write them to the text file but i really need help reading them!

ps. When i go to check the text file I wrote initialized objects i see this: "��srjava.lang.Integer⠤���8Ivaluexrjava.lang.Number������xpsq~sq~"

I have used PrintWriter and File to read and write single object types to and from a text file by parsing the information and placing it to a String array per line in the past. I now have used serialization implementation only to realize I can't read or add objects actually in the text file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {       
       Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
       ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
       String name, title;
       int id, choice, choice2 = 0;
       double wage=0, hours=0, salary=0,bonus=0;
       boolean another = false;
       boolean found = false;
       boolean flag = false;

       list.add(new Manager("Morgan Lin", "Manager",105,120000,20));
       list.add(new Manager("Al Mar", "Manager",102,220000,20));
       list.add(new SalariedEmployee("Harry Morgan", "Salaried Employee",101,89000));

       try {
           FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream (new File ("myObjects.txt"));
           ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
           for(int i = 0; i<list.size();i++) {
           o.writeObject(i);
           }
           o.close();
           fo.close();


       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error initializing stream");
        }
```

I'd like to have something like this in myObjects.txt:

Morgan Lin; Manager; 105; 120000; 20

Al Mar; Manager; 102; 220000;20
Harry Morgan; Salaried Employee;101;89000

Without having to first initialize the objects to the ArrayList in my code.

Comment: Hi, perhaps these articles might be of interest: https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Comment: Actually, it isnot difference between objects while you read or write it. But now, it looks you search something like serilializing

Comment: You could use FileReader / FileWriter to create the text file in the semicolon delimited format that you desire.  You can split each line read into an array of String objects.  You'll have to change your constructors to take String parameters or convert some of the Strings to Integers if you do this.

Comment: This wheel has already been invented: See [Java Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization)