# Read a BigInteger serialized from Java into C#

Tags: c#, java, serialization

I have a `BigInteger` serialized to a file by a Java program using the `writeObject` method from `ObjectOutputStream`.

Can I deserialize it in C#? I tried using the `java.math` and `java.io` classes of `vjslib`, but I get an exception:

> InvalidClassException
>   the class does not match the class of the persisted object for cl = java.lang.Number : __SUID = -8742448824652078965, getSUID(cl) = 3166984097235214156

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you try to deserialize it using vjslib? Please post an example

Answer (score 1):

Do you have control over the serialization step from Java?

If so, I would suggest serializing a byte array, either as binary, or base64, and reading the byte array from the serialized structure.

Then you can pass the byte array to the `System.Numerics.BigInteger` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind ugly hacks: I'd say the easiest (albeit not most efficient) way would be to just write it out as an ASCII String on the Java side, and parse that string on the C# side, instead of using binary de/serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't use serialization for this, since the two versions of `BigInteger` are not compatible - they have different version ids.

You should write the object out in some other way, probably using the byte array from `BigInteger.toByteArray`

Reading this [this question about serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352117/how-does-javas-serialization-work-and-when-it-should-be-used-instead-of-some-oth) might also be insightful for you